# Python syntax error (in the interpreter) after a for loop

Tags: python, file, syntax, syntax-error

I'm running some python code (pasted in) from the console, and getting an unexpected result. Here's what the code looks like:

```
parentfound = False
structfound = False
instruct = False
wordlist = []
fileHandle = open('cont.h')
for line in fileHandle:
    if line is "":
        print "skipping blank line"
        continue
    if "}" in line:
        instruct = False
        index = line.index("}")
        wordlist.append(word)
    pass          
try:
    print wordlist
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

After the for loop, I'd like to print the `wordlist`. No matter what I do, I can't include anything outside the for loop. Here's the error I receive:

```
...     if "}" in line:
...         instruct = False
...         index = line.index("}")
...         wordlist.append(word)
...     pass          
... try:
  File "<stdin>", line 10
    try:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It occurs whether I type the code by hand into the terminal or if I paste it in. I'd appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you!

Comment: It works for me.  Is it possible you have an indentation error, with extra spaces or tabs somewhere?  (There are some logic errors in your code, but at least it runs.)

Comment: what is `word` in `wordlist.append(word)`?

Comment: The code isn't complete -- I pared down as much as I could while still getting an error so it'd be easier to get to the root of the problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `...` prompt in the REPL means that it still hasn't finished the previous block. You will need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line to terminate it first.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a shot. If I include this in a python file, instead of typing it into the interpreter, will I still encounter this error?

Comment: No. This behavior is peculiar to the REPL.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response -- that was driving me crazy. I'll accept the answer as soon as the timer is up!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This also solved my problem too - thanks. Is this behavior, including the `...` prompt, documented somewhere? I must have missed it.

Comment: Sidebar: another solution is to use IPython, which doesn't have these nuances, it seems.