# Foor loop over a string of strings in Biopython

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, biopython

I wrote the following code to download multiple sequences from NCBI.

```
import numpy as np
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email ="user@example.com"
data = np.loadtxt('/home/Documents/XXX.txt', dtype="string")
data
array(['YP_615060', 'YP_615061', 'YP_615062', ..., 'YP_611146',
   'YP_611148', 'YP_611150'], 
  dtype='|S12')
ids=data[:10]
ids_1=data[10:20]
ids_1=",".join(ids_1)
ids_2=data[20:30]
ids_2=",".join(ids_2)
total=(ids, ids_1, ids_2)
for c in total:
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id=c, rettype="fasta", retmode="txt")
handle.read()
```

I get an error

```
 File "<stdin>", line 3
handle.read()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess I am writing the 'foor' loop wrong, but I cannot get what's the problem. It is suppose to be a trivial issues, but I cannot find a way around it.

If I test the for loop and I do not call

```
handle.read()
```

running

```
>>>for c in total:
...     handle=Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id=c, rettype="fasta", retmode="txt")
...
```

the for loop is still waiting for something. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `record = Entrez.read(handle)` (see [documentation](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html))

Comment: I can't spot any syntax errors. Maybe it's on a previous line in your code? The line number is quite low, are you sure it's the correct file?

Comment: @efrem Note, that the `handle.read()` is not part of the loop block. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jens Thanks, but same problem

Comment: is it normal that you put declare data and then put data again at line 5?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGómez Looks like mixed input and output form an interactive session.

Comment: I think the problem is my inexperience. If I do not report handle.read() I would expect the for loop to do its job and stop, but its awaiting for commands.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188921/python-syntax-error-in-the-interpreter-after-a-for-loop

Comment: @AndréLaszlo. Great!!I can accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: I think tobias' answer is correct, it's just that the question has already been asked in a different way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a wild guess, but your code looks like mixed input and output from an interactive session, and I can reproduce your error when pasting chunks of code in interactive mode:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print i
... print "done"
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print "done"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Instead, try pasting *only* the `for` loop and it's body, then hit enter (twice), *then* paste the `handle.read()` line. (That is, assuming that this line is not meant to be part of the loop; if so, fix the indentation.) Alternatively, put all of that code into a file and run that file with `python filename.py`.

Comment: you are right. I updated my question. I do not get why the for loop keeps waiting for a command. Shouldn't just run the command for each element in the string and stop?

Comment: @efrem Is it really "waiting"? When pasting code with indentation, you have to press enter twice to execute it. Or maybe that part of the code is just slow...